# Pegar Dados Função Customizada WP

Tags: php, wordpress

Fiz uma função customizada no functions.php no tema do Wordpress.

Preciso pegar os dados da tabela wp_postmeta, porém não estou conseguindo. Parece ser um problema de tempo de execução(Os dados não estão salvos ainda).

Onde posso colocar a chamada da minha função para ela ser executada, depois que o Wordpress salva os dados do post do Wordpress?

Existe algum callback para ajudar?